# Table of contents separated titles in different pages

Tags: lyx

I am in trouble

I am working in my thesis in lyx and i don't know why the TOC is is separating the titles in different pages when I export to PDF. The titles are from 2 appendix (the two last one).

If anyone can help me I'll be very gratefull
Thx!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That happens to me too. Since I don't know a good solution to this I played with `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{4ex plus 2ex minus 2ex}` to give a little extra space between chapters in the toc. But as I said if you try this "solution" your have to play a little with the space